# Is there a simple way to open ".sty" files by something similar to the "texdoc"?

Tags: packages, texdoc

Is there a simple way to open "`.sty`" files by something similar to the "`texdoc`"? I'm looking for something like `texsty` to simply open `.sty` files.

Comment: Usually `texdoc foo.sty` works. If you're on a bash shell, also `less $(kpsewhich foo.sty)` does the same.

Comment: @egreg: Solutions with `bash` and `kpsewhich` are indeed easy, I like to combine with `start` or `xdg-open` etc instead of `less`. However, the `texdoc` solution at least doesn't work with MiKTeX 2.9, eg I get `Documentation for hyperref.sty could not be found.`

Comment: @egreg How can I open the .sty file in my default latex editor?

Comment: @VahidDamanafshan if you are using bash, just replace `less` in @egreg's suggestion with `emacs` or whatever editor you use and perhaps add a `&` at the end.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Could you please first tell me what a bash shell is?

Comment: @VahidDamanafshan What's your default latex editor?  What's your OS?  In my default editor (TeXShop) there's a menu item "Open .sty file" which does that.  So we need more information.

Comment: @AlanMunn I'm using TL2012 on Win7 with TeXmaker.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I have no problem with opening my `.sty` files. I'm just looking for an easier way to open them.

Comment: @VahidDamanafshan a shell is a command line interpreter in unix/linux operating systems. As you later said you are using windows you probably are using the standard windows cmd command line rather than bash so the `$...`  syntax egreg suggested won't work. (I use bash as my command line on windows but this is by choice, it's not likely to happen by accident:-)

Comment: @egreg: _Usually texdoc foo.sty works_. Thanks for that hint; I wasn't aware of this functionality of texdoc and always went the manual lookup route :-)

Comment: @Daniel With tcsh one can do ``alias texless 'less `kpsewhich \!*`'``; with bash it would be `function texless(){ less $(kpsewhich "$@") ; }`

Comment: @egreg, is there some similar to open `cls` files?

Comment: @Sigur The `texless` trick works for (almost) any file in the TeX distribution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Windows (without cyg)

Native Windows isn't really cut out for this. It's been a while since I did any batch file scripting, but try this:

Save the following as file `texsty.bat` and place it on your `PATH` (or in the working directory of your command prompt):

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`kpsewhich %*.sty`) do "C:\Program Files\Texmaker\texmaker" "%%a"
```

Use as eg `texsty hyperref`. If you want to be able to specify files which do not end in `.sty` (eg `.cls`, `.pdf`, `.dtx`, `.clo`) then you can remove the `.sty` extension from just after the `%*` in the batch file, but then would have to invoke for `sty` files as eg `texsty hyperref.sty` (and it might be better to call it `texstart` instead of `texsty` in that case).

This assumes that Texmaker is installed in the default path. For other editors/paths, one can edit the command line accordingly. It should also be possible to use `start` to use the default program associated with `sty` files, but this doesn't work for me via this batch file...

I got the syntax from [Batch equivalent of Bash backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768608/batch-equivalent-of-bash-backticks).

### Bash (or similar shells)

For completeness, if using `bash`, I would add the following function definition to my `~/.bashrc` file:

```
texsty ()
{
# invoke kpsewhich, but remove any unwanted characters that may show up on Windows
local kpseret="$(kpsewhich "$1.sty" | tr -d '\r')"
if [ -z "$kpseret" ]; then
echo "'$1' not found."
else
xdg-open "$kpseret"
#or for Windows, use start instead of xdg-open:
#start "$kpseret"
fi
}
```

This just wraps the method offered by egreg in his comment into a more convenient function. Again, invoke as eg `texsty hyperref`. Personally, I'd probably prefer the more general `texstart` obtained by removing `.sty` from the `kpsewhich` call and renaming the function, then invoke as eg `texstart hyperref.sty`.

Comment: Thank, but how to "append it to the %* in the batch file."?

Comment: @VahidDamanafshan: I have reversed the answer so that the `.sty` extension is now there by default, and I have explained how to remove it instead of how to add it.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately windows does not have the flexibility of unix commands. This has to be done on two step process or using a script as per the accepted answer.

You use `kpsewhich filename.sty` to locate and then you type the path and the editor name in my case `notepad`. If you doinf this thing often download sublime2 and have it on the path.

[image]

`EDLIN.EXE` not supported anymore! However `EDIT` still works and you can replace `Notepad` with `EDIT` if you like.

This answer is more of a note to myself.